# Prove that the map of $A \mapsto BAB^{-1}$ is an automorphism of the group of all Special Matrices $SL(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

> Let $n \geqslant 1$ be an integer. Prove that for all $B \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, the map $A \mapsto BAB^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Where $S$ is the group of matrices with $\det = 1$.

Here is what I have so far:

Claim: if $A$ belongs to $S$, so does $BAB^{-1}$.

Proof: $\det(CD) = \det(C)\det(D)$ and $\det(C) = 1/\det(C^{-1})$
therefore, $\det(BAB^{-1}) = \det(B)\det(A)\det(B^{-1}) = \det(B) \cdot 1 \cdot \det(B^{-1}) = 1$
therefore $BAB^{-1}$ belongs to $S$

Is this proof enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$SL_n(\mathbb{R})=\{ A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R}):|\det(A)|=1 \},$$ which is a group under matrix multiplication. Remember that an automorphism is a bijective endomorphism; that is, a biyective homomorphism $\varphi:G \to G$, where $G=(G,*)$ is a group. Now, if $\phi:SL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is suh that $\phi(A)=BAB^{-1}$ then $$\phi(AC)=B(AC)B^{-1}=BAI_nCB^{-1}=BA(B^{-1}B)CB^{-1}=(BAB^{-1})(BCB^{-1})=\phi(A)\phi(C),$$ so $\phi$ is an homomorphism.

Now, observe that $$\det(\phi(A))=\det(BAB^{-1})=\det(B)\det(A)\det(B^{-1})=\det(B)\det(A)\frac{1}{\det(B)}=\det(A)=\pm 1,$$ so $\phi$ is surjective ($\phi$ is an epimorphism). Finally, if $\phi(A)=\phi(C)$ then $$BAB^{-1}=BCB^{-1}\Leftrightarrow B^{-1}(BAB^{-1})=B^{-1}(BCB^{-1}) \Leftrightarrow AB^{-1}=AC^{-1} \Leftrightarrow (AB^{-1})B=(CB^{-1})B \Leftrightarrow A=C$$ and hence $\phi$ is injective ($\phi$ is a monomorphism). Therefore $\phi$ is bijective ($\phi$ is an isomorphism). And since $\phi$ goes from $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ ont the same set we conclude that $\phi$ is an automorphism.

**NOTE:** Here $I_n$ denotates the identity matrix of order $n$.

Comment: Which operation are you putting on $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$? I guess you should check your answer

Comment: Thanks Tancerdi, I already edited the post! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Although check the definition of the special linear group. Then note that you didn't show that $\phi$ is surjective (when you thinked to). My hint is to explicit the inverse of $\phi$

Comment: As Tancredi pointed out, this is incorrect as it stands.  Your intended proof of surjectivity, using determinants, just reproduces MarkJ's proof that $\operatorname{SL}_n$ is invariant under $\phi$, and does not prove surjectivity.    Let us augment your notation by writing $\phi_B(A)  = B^{-1} A B$.  To prove that $\phi_B$ is an isomorphism, observe that $\phi_{B^{-1}} = (\phi_B)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Called $\gamma_B$ the application defined by $\gamma_B(A)=BAB^{-1}$ for every $A\in SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ you should note that: $1)$ $\gamma_B$ is well-defined, actually the only thing you proved (which can be sufficient if you can assume  the following).
$2)\ \gamma_B(I_n)=I_n$ (obvious).
$3)\ \gamma_B(AA')=\gamma_B(A)\gamma(A')$ (easy).
$4)\ \gamma_B$ are all invertible (pretty simple giving the explict inverse).
Now, perhaps you can assume pretty much of these facts as known (the conjugation gives arise to an automorphism) but the exercise is too easy (in my opinion) to jump over these assumptions

Answer (score 1):

It's best to separate out the part that has nothing to do specifically with $\operatorname{SL}_n$ and $\operatorname{GL}_n$.

Lemma.  If $N \subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup, then for all $g \in G$, $n \mapsto g n g^{-1}$ is an automorphisms of $N$.

Prove this if you don't think it can be assumed, and cite it or allude to it otherwise.  Then it just remains to show $\operatorname{SL}_n$ is normal in $\operatorname{GL}_n$, and that is what you did with your determinant argument.